# Custom membership in ASP.NET MVC error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I tried to implement own membership in asp.net mvc by inheriting from base class.

```
public override void CreateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        this.repository.CreateUser(username, password);
    }
```

But, when I tried to build the application.I got the following error.

```
Membership.CreateUser(string, string)': no suitable method found to override    
Membership does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.CreateUser(string, string, string, string, string, bool, object, out System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus)'
```

I tried to change the parameter in the original function,but I got same sort of error.
Please guide me, I am newbie in ASP.NET and C#.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: This isn't a question? You're not even saying if there is an error?  What is your base class.

Comment: @Andorbal I have written the error.

Comment: It tells you very clearly that the signature `string, string` does not exist, and what it should be.

Comment: @RudiVisser I want to know that whether I need to implement method with same overload and same return object like abstract one

Comment: Well, you can certainly implement a new version of `CreateUser` with just those 2 parameters, but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Why not try public void CreateUser instead of public override void..

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
public void CreateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            this.repository.CreateUser(username, password);
        }
```

or this one

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx) that will guide you How to: Implement a Custom Membership User